# Springboot project without service layer

Tags: spring-boot, domain-driven-design

I am working on a project which has slightly different design. In all tutorials basically there are POJOs which are representing Models and all the business logic are implemented in service layers. In my project it is implemented in a way that there is not service layer and all the logic are implemented in Model classes by defining some static methods. Some says that it is because of Domain Driven Design but I am not really sure about it.

Putting all the logic inside of the POJOs looks messy for me. I would like to understand what is the benefit of this design and is if it is good software practice to implement business logic without service layer ?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a bad idea to use a bunch of static methods, also adding logic in the DTOs is not recommended.

There is not a strict universally accepted rule about creating a service layer, I think what is very important is that the application design is modular and testable.

This is why the service layer pattern comes in handy:

- business logic is confined in a layer where you can abstract the complexity into a set of functionality made available to the other layers
- application logic is not scattered across packages and classes, simplify the evolution and make possible to refactoring for accommodating future changes
- service classes can be tested independently (again critical for refactoring)

Comment: Actually it is no my DTO, I use separate DTO object for responses.

Comment: Sorry, I meant POJO (in DTO would be as bad though)